# Which finger on right hand to use to play G note on piano in Twinkle Twinkle Little Star?

Tags: piano, fingering

When my daughter learned piano the first time one year ago, the teacher let us use this fingering:

```
CC GG AA G FF EE DD C
11 55 55 5 44 33 22 1
```

We stop learning for a while and we start again. However, this new teacher let us use this fingering:

```
CC GG AA G FF EE DD C
11 44 55 4 44 33 22 1
```

We are quite confused.

Comment: Fingering is rarely an absolute question of right or wrong.  How old is your daughter?

Answer (score 9):

Both are acceptable, so in this case, I suggest using the fingering recommended by the current teacher. However, if making the change is proving difficult, then have a parent-teacher conversation to acknowledge the difficulty and ask to use the old fingering for this song. A good teacher will be flexible. (And the best teachers would already have recognized the confusion and allowed the student to play in the familiar way or gauged how to surmount any difficulty in switching.)

The differences between the two fingerings amount to the following:

1. The 55 55 5 fingering ("repeated 5s") requires two shifts of the hand (from G to A, then back to G); whereas, the 11 44 55 4 44 fingering ("repeated 4s") requires "opening" the hand (from C [11] to G [44] and only one shift (from G [4] to F [44]). Also, the two hand-shifts in the "repeated 5s" fingering happen close together in the music, while the adjustments in the "repeated 4s" fingering are more separated from each other.
2. In the "repeated 4s" fingering, the hand movements better match the phrasing of the music, the hand-shift coming at a break between phrases.

```
Twink - le, twink - le, lit - tle star.
1       1   4       4   5     5   4
    (hand "opens")                     (hand shift)

1       1   5       5   5     5   5
                (hand shift)(hand shift)

How I won - der what you are.
4   4 3     3   2    2   1
4   4 3     3   2    2   1
```

3. An advantage to the "repeated 5s" fingering is that the hand never has to leave "five-finger position", a common starting point for learning in which each finger is on consecutive notes — C D E F G.

Comment: I would prefer the new fingering because it introduces the idea of changing hand position to prepare for what is coming.

Comment: @Peter I'm with you, for the same reason. And it's better fingering practice anyway, so good to instill proper fingering early.

Comment: How about  5 4 for G G, then 3 4 for F F ? This way the hand moves along the keys' changing direction?

Comment: @GrandAdagio I like it. Very clever. The hand movement matching the direction of the music is a great benefit. The only reason I can think of not to use it with a beginner is that it can be confusing to play the same note with different fingers, but that would depend on the particular learner.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I'm flattered :) Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3):

In the early stages of learning piano, the hand(s) will be anchored over just 5 notes - and tunes will accommodate this. That makes it easy to play tunes - no need to look at the keys. But when the tune strays beyond the 5 notes, something has to change.

One option is to stretch and allow the pinky to play ^5 *and* ^6. The whole hand could actually slide a little to the right for ^6, then back to the 'safe' position for the rest.

Another option is to stretch the whole hand, as new teacher advocates, so ^5 is played by finger 4, putting pinky over ^6. Another good reason this works *now* is probably tat your daughter has grown somewhat in the intervening year, and that stretch isn't really a stretch. It also prepares her for moving out of that 'safe' 5 fingers for 5 notes syndrome.

With fingering of anything, at any level,I advocate the student trying out all available options, not just blindly following teacher's choice, as there may be an even better one that hasn't been used so far. It will depend on the piece, and the student's physical hand structure, as we all differ . A really good teacher will be able to justify and explain why s/he recommends certain things - ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

The primary source of confusion is that you think there's a "correct" way. There's none. It's like picking a color for an apple in a picture: should it be green? Red? Yellow?

Sticking to one version when learning might be a good idea because reasonable fingering helps muscle memory. Learning to switch fingerings might also be a good idea because that helps improvise and read a vista (citation required).

At the level of playing "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star" - none of the above really matters.

Comment: It’s perhaps more like “What kind of shoes should my daughter wear — pull-on, velcro, buckle, lace-up?” There’s no single absolute right answer, but it’s not just an arbitrary choice like the apple colour either — depending on the child’s age, competence, and other so on, some answers may well be better than others for this specific stage.

Comment: @PLL I can imagine some really bad fingerings, certainly. But, like in case of the shoes, it's not something to overthink. There's a lot of variables, there will be much more tunes than just "Twinkle, twinkle...". I think this is something that is hard to get wrong :)

Comment: @PLL: To put it another way: you will not get a better fingering, specific to your child, by asking for it on the Internet. Same with shoes: we don't know the context, we don't know the shoes, we don't know the child's manual skills, we don't know her motivation. If your kindergarten teacher says that lace-up is fine, then it's probably fine, and certainly not something to be confused about.